# Interactive proofs with computation bounded Merlin

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, interactive-proofs

Consider usual interactive proofs (Arthur is polynomial-time bounded and can use random bits)

where computation power of Merlin is bounded by polynomial-size circuits.

For example, every unary NP-language can be decided in the corresponding model. (There exists a poly($n$)-size circuit that on input $1^n$ outputs a certificate if it exists.)

Are there any researches about this model?

Comment: Do you mean that for every string in the language, there exists a circuit implementing Merlin for this particular input, or do you require one circuit for each input length whose inputs include the original input? In the former case, the class you get is MA, in the latter case it's oblivious MA.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I mean one circuit with size poly($n$) for all inputs of length $n$.
I do not understand how to get MA...

Comment: Oblivious MA, then. The point is that all Merlin needs to do is send his circuit; then Arthur can simulate it himself without further interaction.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Could you please explain what is ``Oblivious MA" or give a reference?

Comment: https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:O#oma

Comment: You might want to look at Section 3 in the following paper:
https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2011/023/